# Black foliage turning green?

Tags: sunlight, foliage, dahlias

I bought a beautiful dahlia with black foliage, but it has turned green. I am in Seattle, the summer has turned the fall, and the plant is in full sun. It is blooming and looks very healthy.

What causes dark-foliaged plants to lose their darkness? Is there anything I can do to bring back the black leaves?

Comment: It's a sun thing, for sure. Maybe there's nothing you can do with the lowering sun in Fall and Winter. After dormancy, you should get to black in Summertime.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect (no experience with black specifically, so not an answer) that it's similar to my green-and-white variegated stuff turning all green where there's less sunlight. Plant is adapting by optimizing production for the light available, and deleting the frivolous coloration to compensate for less light.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas